# how to read r data.frame in .dump file

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in .dump file. I was able to read it using source function in r. Could someone explain how this was generated and some reference on this?

The .dump file(opened in r) looks (in spirit) like:

```
'data'<-structure(.Data = list(c(1,1,1,2), c(2,2,2,2)), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: A `dump` file is just a textual store of the output from `dput`. It is not always a great way of storing objects, fyi; if you want efficient and as near perfect of storing attributes, as well as perfect "rehydration" of the data, I'd go with `saveRDS` (though it cannot be read or parsed by non-R tools). Regardless, try `dump("mtcars", "mtcars.dump")` and see that it (as [it reads](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dump.html)) takes a vector of object *names* and stores *"text representations of the objects in a file"*.

Comment: You can use `help` to provide a faster explanation of functions you don't understand. While some functions' documentation can be rather obscure, I think [`help("dump")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dump.html) (or more briefly, `?dump`) reads fairly well given what it does.

Comment: Thanks. This certainly helps. What I was confused about was why save it as .dump file instead .R file like in the description of dump?

Comment: You can name the file `"myfile.quux"` and it won't change anything (other than what Windows will think to do with the file), you will still be able to `source("myfile.quux")` with the same success. Name it `dump.R` if you want, it's certainly more consistent (from the OS's point of view) than the help's `.Rdmped` file extension (which makes no sense to me).